# Replace fields in yaml file by python

Tags: python, yaml, editing

I need to edit the next  yaml file with python code :

```
# This is a sample YAML file for running est.
# - Here I have the comments 1
# - Here I have comments 2


# Robust compare
# - Here I have comments 3
# - Here I have comments 4

job_name: Field1 

strategy_num: &strategy_num

dir_base   : &dir_base  high_vals

from_date_is: &from_date 20150101
to_date_is  : &to_date   20161231

# Here I have comments 5
dir: D:\Alex
run_mode      : debug

analyses:
  # Simulate for all dates (IS)
  - kind: RunStrat
    label: tr
    done: false
    dry_run: false
    from_date: *from_date
    to_date  : *to_date
    configs_to_test_dir: configs_temp
```

configs_to_run_dir: configs_to_run

I need to replace high_vals by other_high_vals  and configs_temp by other_configs_temp.
Everything I tried doesn't work
Last try:

```
def change_yaml(path_to_yaml):
    try:
        with open(path_to_yaml) as yaml_file:
            print(path_to_yaml)
            doc = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)

        doc['dir_base'][1] = 'other_dir_base'
        doc['analyses']['configs_to_test_dir'] = other_configs_temp

    except EnvironmentError as e:
        raise ValueError('Could not open yaml file {}:\n{}'.format(path_to_yaml, e))

    try:
        with open(path_to_yaml, 'w') as yaml_file:
            yaml.dump(doc, yaml_file)
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        raise ValueError('Could not write to yaml file {}:\n{}'.format( path_to_yaml , e)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Arount: `with` limits context only for `yaml_file` variable. Other variables defined under `with` are visible outside of it too.

Comment: ^ true, comment will be removed in 3, 2, 1 GO. (this one will be deleted soon too)

Comment: I'm sorry , I don't understand how it helps me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
doc['dir_base'][1] = 'other_dir_base'
```

assumes that the value for the key `dir_base` can be indexed, but that value is the scalar `high_vals` and since that is loaded as a string in Python you are trying to do the equivalent of:

```
s= 'high_vals'
s[1] = 'other_dir_base'
```

which will give a `TypeError`.

You probably want to do:

```
doc['dir_base'] = 'other_dir_base'
```